# jQuery off click event from click event's function's interval's function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm creating a very simple game - it starts when user clicks the area,
and should stop after 10seconds so I have code like this:

```
$('#area').click(function(){
  var timer = setInterval(function(){ 
     clearInterval(timer);
     $(this).off('click'); //this is taking window as "this" 
  }, 1000);
});
```

But as you can see from the code `$(this).off('click');` is not doing what I want - how to get to the `$('#area')`'s **`this`** in this scope? (click event's function's interval's function).
I hope you understood my question correctly, if dont please comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the value of `this` in the click handler (which will be the element clicked on) so you can use it within the timer function. Try this:

```
$('#area').click(function(){
    var $area = $(this);
    var timer = setInterval(function(){ 
        clearInterval(timer);
        $area.off('click');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: is the $ between var and area important here ?

Comment: @jave.web it's not required syntactically, it's a convention to show that the variable is used to hold a jQuery object.

Comment: I thought so :) I just wanted to be sure, anyway it is working - funny thing I was var-ing just 'this' - not as a jQuery object :) Thanks. BTW In the final code I didnt needed this but Its still good to know :) (I will accept this as an answer ASAP ;)